# LINQ Dynamic query nullable field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic-linq

Suppose an SQL table 'employees' (containing a nullable datetime field called 'endDate')

static LINQ:

```
dim  result = db.employees.where(function(c) not(c.endDate.hasValue))
```

Works perfectly!

dynamic LINQ:

```
dim  result = db.employees.where("it.endDate == null")
```

Throws an error

> Operator '=' incompatible with operand types 'DateTime?' and 'Boolean'

Now I am completely blocked in my project because of this issue.
Any of you already faced this problem ?

Thanks a lot in advance - zSkk

Answer (score 2):

there is nothing like ==(double equal) in SQL , use =(single equal) if you want to compare.

Answer (score 2):

it.endDate is null is **not going to work**.... LINQ Dynamic expects **it.endDate == null**

Answer (score 1):

it should be `it.endDate is null`

Comment: What a shame ! I am sorry but I was correcting the code in the wrong project... 'it.endDate == null' was the correct syntax. Thanks a lot and sorry for the wasted time

Comment: I guess it could be useful for others if you post a reply stating the right answer, then mark it as "answered" =)

Answer (score 0):

try `IS`

```
Dim  result = db.employees.Where("it.endDate IS null")
```